# Installing networkx Python package in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, installation, networkx

How to install and how to compile networkx python on QGIS?

I always get an error that `no module named networkx` in the console of QGIS.

I copied the file networkx in `C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages` and there are not change.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange. Could you explain how you are trying to install it? Did you follow the documentation e.g. http://networkx.github.com/documentation/latest/install.html#source-archive-file ?

Comment: i am trying to install networkx Python library in QGIS after i installed it,in order to Analyze spatial graphs in QGIS with Python

Answer (score 5):

> I copied the file networkx

It is not a simple file, it is a folder with many files. You must place the entire unzipped networkx folder in C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages (because it is a simple module)

In general, to use a Python module, you must first install it:

```
python setup.py install
```

As on Windows, QGIS uses its own version of Python (not in the Windows's registry), without a Python shell, you can:

1. use the bootstrapped installer for setuptools of [Nathan's QGIS Blog](http://nathanw.net/2012/12/19/installing-python-setuptools-into-osgeo4w-python/), which will install directly the module into a folder rather than looking in the registry
2. download  the networkx version of  Christoph Gohlke at [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#networkx), unzip it (it is a .exe file but you can directly unzip it) and place the resulting folder in C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages.

After that, in the Python console of QGIS:

```
import networkx
networkx.__file__
'C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.pyc'
```

or

```
'C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\networkx-1.7-py2.7.egg\networkx\__init__.pyc'
```

depending on how you installed the module

Comment: thank you bro for your help,but i did installed python on QGIS and i did place networkx on "C:\Program Files\Quantum GIS Lisboa\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages" but nothing happend
the same mistake,always after i opened QGIS and open console python and i call networkx "import networkx " it's says that no module named networkx,

Comment: never mind,i fond the problem,its in networkx i palced it but hte hole file it must palce the Content of the file networkx in the site packages,htank you again my friend

Comment: @gene I tried the second solution and it worked. Thanks A LOT!

Comment: @gene I've tried to do what you said but have an ImportError: No module named decorator

Comment: install the [decorator](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to install `networkx` python module to run it from QGIS is to use OSGeo4W installer. It will handle all the dependencies that `networkx` rely on.

Download  OSGeo4W Network installer from [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) download page, then right-click the EXE file and select `Run as Administrator`, select `Advance install` and follow the steps until you find the following window:

[image]

In the `Search` box write `networkx` and you will have two versions located under Libs: one for python 2 and the other for python 3. Choose `networkx` for python 2 because this what is currently used in QGIS 2.X.X and click on `Next` to install. In the image above it is written `Keep` because it is already installed, but for the first time installation you have to click `Install`.

When the installation finishes successfully, you can import `networkx` module directly from inside QGIS Python Console, and it will not give an import error.

[image]