# Error while importing networkx module in QGIS 2.18.16

Tags: qgis-2, import, networkx

I am trying to import networkx module in QGIS 2.18.16 but getting the error message. Any suggestions?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 607, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from networkx import release
ImportError: cannot import name release
```

Comment: [@Hachana](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/127631/hachana), have you seen this article [How to install networkx python in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/52733/how-to-install-networkx-python-in-qgis)